# Having problem Understanding fork() hierarchy tree

Tags: c++, c, fork

I have this Code that I can't understand. I understood the basics of fork() but I don't understand the Hierarchical tree for this process.
The code is like this:

```
main()
{
    fork();
    if(fork()){
        printf("A");
    }
    else{
        printf("B");
    }
}
```

The output is A A B B. How does this happen? I get it why A is printed twice but why is B printed? How does the hierarchical tree work here?

Comment: did you try to work it out yourself?

Comment: I recommend you draw it out on paper.

Comment: How many letters do you expect? and then think about which letters should be printed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i actually need help with that

Comment: @mch i was not expecting B to be printed at all but there it is and there are 2 Bs

Comment: i did @user253751 . i was expecting only A to be printed.

Comment: You remember that `fork()` returns `0` in the newly created child process? And do you remember that the newly created child process starts exactly with the returning of the `fork` call? And lastly, do you also remember that `0` is considered to be `false` when used in a condition?

Comment: Why were you expecting only A to be printed?

Comment: @user253751 i thought the if statement would be true and it would only print As

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "`fork()` returns `0` in the newly created child process" i didn't know this

Comment: @TaRaNeH Then I'm sorry to say that whatever resource you're using to learn about processes and `fork` seems to be very inadequate. That `fork` have *two* returns (one in the parent and one in the child) and that `fork` returns `0` in the child is well-specified and well-documented, even rather bad tutorials, books or classes should have had that information. It's the standard way to detect if you're in the parent or child process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay lets "draw" the process tree created by this program (using `P` for parent process, and `C` for child process):

```
                      fork()
                        ^
                       / \
                       | |
                       P C
                       | |
          /------------/ \------------\
          |                           |
        fork                        fork
          ^                           ^
         / \                         / \
         | |                         | |
         P C                         P C
         | |                         | |
   /-----/ \----\              /-----/ \----\
   |            |              |            |
printf("A")  printf("B")    printf("A")  printf("B")
```

First there's a `fork()` without condition. That means the parent and child processes both continue on the same path through the program.

Then comes the second `fork()` call. Both the original parent and child does this fork. In the new fork, the new parent processes will have a non-zero return value, meaning the condition is `true` and they will print `"A"`. The new child processes will have a zero return value, which is `false` and they will go on to print `"B"`.

The exact order the processes will run is unspecified, and therefore the exact output will be unpredictable. But it will print `"A"` twice and `"B"` twice.

Comment: i think i understand it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*The output is A A B B* -> Output can vary between runs because of concurrency I have this [image]

So the logic is the following: the first fork makes one more process to execute the same program after the first fork and each of the two processes creates one more process which prints `B` and then prints `A` by its own soo you get 4 processes in total

Comment: so correct me if i understood wrong, the parent (p1) creates a child (p2) and those 2 each create a child process (p3 and p4) so the parent has 2 children (p2 and p3) and the child (p2) has it's own child (p4). right?

Comment: @TaRaNeH, right